# Hadoop: How to send MultipleOutputs to 2 different paths / file systems?

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, hdfs

I've got MultipleOutputs configured to generate 2 named outputs. I'd like to send one to `s3n://` and one to `hdfs://`

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not currently possible to do with the available API.

The `MultipleOutputs` class if Hadoop MapReduce currently works only for sub-directory (of the configured output directory) output names, which lets it take care of the [side-effects caused by speculative execution](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/FAQ#Can_I_write_create.2BAC8-write-to_hdfs_files_directly_from_map.2BAC8-reduce_tasks.3F).

However, you could re-implement the class (or derive from it), to support this as its not impossible to achieve. You may need a more complex OutputCommitter implementation as well, if you plan on making your implementation support speculative execution.